# How to format UTC timestamp without localization (Angular 4+)

Tags: angular, highcharts, utc, dst

I am using highcharts to display some time series data into a line chart. The data I need to display are provided with an UTC timestamp so I configured highcharts to use UTC. This works great when I'm using the highcharts integrated date formatter but I need the display the time labels on the X-Axis of the line chart with differrent format regarding on the locale set by the user. So I have to implement an custom label formatter which can be injected into highcharts. For this I use angular's DatePipe for formatting the timestamp to the required format.

```
formatter: function () {
  let format = 'HH:mm'; // default format

  if (!!culture) {
    format = culture[this.dateTimeLabelFormat];  // dictionary with formats for various cultures
  }

  var dp = new DatePipe(locale);  // e.g. 'en', 'de', 'fr'
  return dp.transform(this.value, format, 'UTC'); // this.values is an UTC timestamp e.g. 1573807971000
}
```

The code is working great with one exception -> **daylight saving time**. I hoped to avoid this problem by using utc but on the 31st march 2019 the DatePipe formats the timestamp for 02:00 AM UTC to 03:00 AM even if I configure the DatePipe with UTC as timezone.

This is how the X-Axis of the line chart is displayed (notice 03:00 is duplicated) :

[image: This is are the labels on the X-Axis for 31st March 2019]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zj1xwv

How can I format UTC time regardless of the timezone?

Comment: Hi @RDaniel, Could you reproduce the issue in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, here it the issue to reproduce. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zj1xwv . I think that the problem is the way the angular DatePipe is formatting the date and not highcharts itself. I believe I have already found a workaround to my problem -> use highcharts internal dateFormat method  of the time class.

Comment: Great to hear that! Please do not hesitate to ask if you have further questions.

Comment: It seems that I still cannot solve the problem using Highcharts dateFormat Method. The problem is that my application uses the ISO 8601 date-time format and Hicharts expects a php strftime format. Is there a way to configure Highchart to use ISO 8601 format?

Comment: Have you checked the `Time` class API options? https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Time